# Can someone please help me with JavaScript array like this code that i shared to you?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

```js
var input = [
  ["0001", "Roman", "USA", "21/05/1989", "read"],
  ["0002", "jack", "UK", "10/10/1992", "singing"],
  ["0003", "harry", "Poland", "25/12/1965", "cook"],
  ["0004", "Malay", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Sport"]
]

function Handling() {
  // ...
}
```

Can someone please help me with this array problem?

The result should be like this:

> ```
> ID:  0001
> Name:  Roman
> Born Place:  USA 21/05/1989
> Hobby:  read
> ```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

Destructure it, and return an object with shorthand properties

```js
var input = [
            ["0001", "Roman", "USA", "21/05/1989", "read"],
            ["0002", "jack", "UK", "10/10/1992", "singing"],
            ["0003", "harry", "Poland", "25/12/1965", "cook"],
            ["0004", "Malay", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Sport"] ]
            
let result = input.map(([ID, Name, BornPlace, Birthday, Hobby ]) => ({ID, Name, ["Born Place"]:BornPlace, Birthday, Hobby}))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect, beautiful use of destructuring.

Comment: awsome ! simple  and powerful use of distructuring :D

Comment: simple problems require simple solutions!

Answer (score 3):

```js
var input = [
            ["0001", "Roman", "USA", "21/05/1989", "read"],
            ["0002", "jack", "UK", "10/10/1992", "singing"],
            ["0003", "harry", "Poland", "25/12/1965", "cook"],
            ["0004", "Malay", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Sport"]
]

let objArray = input.map(val =>{
  let obj = {};
  obj.ID = val[0];
  obj.Name = val[1];
  obj["Born Place"] = `${val[2]} ${val[3]}`;
  obj.hobby = val[4];
  return obj;
})

console.log(objArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Handling(data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         console.log("ID:" + data[i][0] + "\n")
         console.log("Name:" + data[i][1] + "\n")
         console.log("Place:" + data[i][2] + "\n")
         console.log("Born:" + data[i][3] + "\n")
         console.log("Hobby:" + data[i][4] + "\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and template string to get array of strings in required format.

```js
var input = [
            ["0001", "Roman", "USA", "21/05/1989", "read"],
            ["0002", "jack", "UK", "10/10/1992", "singing"],
            ["0003", "harry", "Poland", "25/12/1965", "cook"],
            ["0004", "Malay", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Sport"]
   ]

const Handling = arr => input.map(arr => 
  `ID: ${arr[0]} Name: ${arr[1]} Born Place: ${arr[2]} ${arr[3]} Hobby: ${arr[4]}`)

console.log(Handling(input))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily convert the matrix to a JSON array.

You just need the data and the fields, since your example data does not have a header row.

Not sure if you were wondering how to render this in HTML, but you can use template literals to display the data, after you transform it. The rendering is very extensible and each step is de-coupled from the previous.

```js
const fields = [ 'ID', 'Name', 'Place of Birth', 'Date of Birth', 'Hobby' ];
const data = [
  [ "0001" , "Roman" , "USA"       , "21/05/1989" , "Reading" ],
  [ "0002" , "Jack"  , "UK"        , "10/10/1992" , "Singing" ],
  [ "0003" , "Harry" , "Poland"    , "25/12/1965" , "Cooking" ],
  [ "0004" , "Malay" , "Martapura" , "6/4/1970"   , "Sports"  ]
];
const opts = {
  fields: {
    'Date of Birth': {
      hidden: true
    },
    'Place of Birth': {
      render: (value, field, data) => {
        return [value, data['Date of Birth'], ].join(' ');
      }
    }
  }
};

const main = () => {
  const jsonData = matrixToJson(data, {
    header: false,
    fields: fields
  });

  displayInHTML(jsonData, opts);
  displayInConsole(jsonData, opts);
};

const displayInHTML = (jsonData, opts) => {
  document.body.innerHTML = renderPeople(jsonData, opts);
};

const renderPeople = (people, opts) => {
  return `<div class="people">${people.map(person => {
    return renderPerson(person, opts);
  }).join('')}</div>`
};

const renderPerson = (person, opts) => {
  return `<div class="person">${filterFields(person, opts).map(field => {
    return renderInfo(field, person[field], person, opts);
  }).join('')}</div>`;
};

const renderInfo = (key, value, person, opts) => {
  return `<div class="info">
    <label>${key}</label>
    <span>${renderValue(value, key, person, opts)}</span>
  </div>`;
};

const displayInConsole = (people, opts) => {
  console.log(people.map(person => {
    return filterFields(person, opts).map((field, index) => {
      return `${field}: ${renderValue(person[field], field, person, opts)}`;
    }).join('\n');
  }).join('\n\n'));
};

// Shared functions

const renderValue = (value, field, person, opts) => {
  if (opts.fields[field] && opts.fields[field].render) {
    return opts.fields[field].render(value, field, person);
  }
  return value;
};

const filterFields = (person, opts) => {
  return Object.keys(person).filter(key => {
    return opts.fields[key] == null ? true
      : !(opts.fields[key].hidden === true);
  })
};

const matrixToJson = (data, config) => {
  const opts = Object.assign({ header : true, fields : [] }, config);
  const fields = opts.header ? data[0] : opts.fields;
  return (opts.header === false ? data.slice(1) : data).map(row => {
    return fields.reduce((res, field, index) => ({...res, [field] : row[index]}), {});
  });
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 33% !important; color: #000; }

body {
  background: #111;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.person {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border: thin solid #444;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #222;
}

.person .info label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.person .info label:after {
  content: ':';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though your question doesn't specify what would be return type of the **Handling function**, If your expected return type a Object check following

```js
var input = [
  ["0001", "Roman", "USA", "21/05/1989", "read"],
  ["0002", "jack", "UK", "10/10/1992", "singing"],
  ["0003", "harry", "Poland", "25/12/1965", "cook"],
  ["0004", "Malay", "Martapura", "6/4/1970", "Sport"]
]

function Handling(input) {
  const mapper = () => {
    const keys = ['ID', 'Name', 'Born Place', 'Born Place', 'Hobby'];
    return arr => arr.reduce((acc, x, index) => {
      const key = keys[index];
      acc[key] = (acc[key] && acc[key] + " " + x) || x;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };
  return input.map(mapper())
}
console.log(Handling(input));
```